# Parse xml from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Currently I have xml stored in a ms sql dbase and **not a file**. Here's a small sample.

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table1>
<billTo_lastName>asdf</billTo_lastName>
<orderAmount>160.00</orderAmount>
<billTo_street1>asdf</billTo_street1>
<card_accountNumber>############1111</card_accountNumber>
</Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Currently I'm returning the result in a **Datable**.

What would be the best way to parse the above and display it on a page.
The page display is just for informational review. No additional processing will be done to the xml.

I would like the page to display something along these lines.

```
billTo_lastName: asdf
orderAmount: 160.00
etc.
```

Comment: Is the XML stored in an XML data typed field in the database?

Comment: You question is not 100% clear.

What do you need that parsed data for? Are you going to do additional processing on parsed data? How do you want it to be displayed like?

Comment: The field is a varchar max.

Comment: Not the best way to store XML data. If you had it in an XML type, you could use the SQL functions to query the XML in situ. Can you not use one of the built in data sources? This may help you on your way: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092706-1.aspx

Comment: I thought about that. But the data is just informational. I don't really need to query it at the moment.

Comment: That may be so, but if it was in an XML data type you could simply extract the values from the XML straight into a string (HTML for example) and write that into the response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on how you want to process it. One way is to create an `XmlDocument` and then call [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx):

```
// get the data from the data table, into a string.

// then create an XML document and load the string
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(dataString);
```

If you want to use Linq-to-Xml, you'd create an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx):

```
var element = XElement.Load(dataString);
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Jim for pointing me in the right direction. XmlDocuments LoadXml works just fine.
I then was able to put that into an XmlNodeList and selected the top node.
Did XmlNode and looped through the child nodes.

```
    DataTable dt = sqlselect(sqlQuery, parameter);
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(dt.Rows[0]["ua_post"].ToString());

    XmlNodeList nl = doc.SelectNodes("NewDataSet");
    XmlNode root = nl[0];

    foreach (XmlNode xnode in root.ChildNodes[0])
    {
        string name = xnode.Name;
        string value = xnode.InnerText;
        string nv = "<b>" + name + ":</b> " + value;
        Label1.Text += nv + " <br />" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

And I get a simple display on a page.

```
    billTo_lastName: asdf 
    orderAmount: 160.00 
    billTo_street1: asdf 
    card_accountNumber: ############1111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return them as columns from Database into DataTable and then display them using any datacontrol with ItemTemplates For example:

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml = '<NewDataSet>
<Table1>
<billTo_lastName>asdf</billTo_lastName>
<orderAmount>160.00</orderAmount>
<billTo_street1>asdf</billTo_street1>
<card_accountNumber>############1111</card_accountNumber>
</Table1>
</NewDataSet>'

;with cte as (    
  select @xml xmlstring
)
SELECT 
xmlstring.value('(/NewDataSet//Table1/billTo_lastName/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
 as billTo_lastName,
xmlstring.value('(/NewDataSet//Table1/orderAmount/node())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') 
as orderAmount
FROM cte
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10738)