# How can I parse XML from database field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Working with the following XML.

```
<TEMPLATE>
<TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_ONE" data_type="8" tag="TEST_ONE" required="0" is_radio="0" default_value="" SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST" />
<TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_TWO" data_type="8" tag="TEST_TWO" required="0" is_radio="0" default_value="" SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST" />
<TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_THREE" data_type="8" tag="TEST_THREE" required="0" is_radio="0" default_value="" SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST" />
```

I'm trying to obtain the following - or something similar in which I can read the fields efficiently.
[image]

I've tried following several other questions and found the 3rd answer of this question promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/15349737/8715626 --because I want to be able to parse in SQL and not using an external language or creating a file. If creating a file is easier, please feel free to share. I've tried several of variations of the code below and I either get a "blank" or a NULL.

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml = (SELECT xml_field from fooXMLtable)

select @xml

;with cte as (    
  select @xml xmlstring
)
SELECT 
xmlstring.value('(/TEMPLATE//TEMPLATE_FIELD/prompt/node())[3]','VARCHAR(max)')
as prompt
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Nahuatl_C137, you obviously didn't read comment for the solution you accepted as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MSSQL, this should work:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML = '<TEMPLATE>
<TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_ONE" data_type="8" tag="TEST_ONE" required="0" is_radio="0" default_value="" SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST" />
<TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_TWO" data_type="8" tag="TEST_TWO" required="0" is_radio="0" default_value="" SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST" />
<TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_THREE" data_type="8" tag="TEST_THREE" required="0" is_radio="0" default_value="" SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST" />
</TEMPLATE>'

SELECT 
    T.C.value('./@prompt', 'nvarchar(50)') as Prompt,
    T.C.value('./@data_type', 'int') as DataType,
    T.C.value('./@tag', 'nvarchar(50)') as Tag,
    T.C.value('./@required', 'bit') as Required,
    T.C.value('./@is_radio', 'bit') as IsRadio,
    T.C.value('./@default_value', 'nvarchar(max)') as DefaultValue,
    T.C.value('./@SQL', 'nvarchar(max)') as Query
FROM   @xml.nodes('/TEMPLATE/TEMPLATE_FIELD') T(C)
```

Comment: (1) It is inefficient to use `//` in the `.nodes()` method XPath expression. It is causing to traverse the entire XML. (2) The OP XML is in the DB table, not in the variable.

Comment: And your answer is better :-)

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following solution.

It is a minimal reproducible example. You can copy it as-is to SSMS, run it, and explore what it does.

It is using XQuery and its methods: `.nodes()` and `.value()`.

There is no need to use a temporary T-SQL variable `@xml` as an XML data placeholder.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<TEMPLATE>
    <TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_ONE" data_type="8" tag="TEST_ONE" required="0"
                    is_radio="0" default_value=""
                    SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST"/>
    <TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_TWO" data_type="8" tag="TEST_TWO" required="0"
                    is_radio="0" default_value=""
                    SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST"/>
    <TEMPLATE_FIELD prompt="TEST_THREE" data_type="8" tag="TEST_THREE"
                    required="0" is_radio="0" default_value=""
                    SQL="SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST"/>
</TEMPLATE>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID 
    , c.value('@prompt', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS prompt
    , c.value('@data_type', 'INT') AS data_type
    , c.value('@tag', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS tag
    , c.value('@required', 'INT') AS [required]
    , c.value('@is_radio', 'INT') AS [is_radio]
    , c.value('@default_value', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS default_value
    , c.value('@SQL', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [SQL]
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/TEMPLATE/TEMPLATE_FIELD') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
| ID |   prompt   | data_type |    tag     | required | is_radio | default_value |               SQL               |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | TEST_ONE   |         8 | TEST_ONE   |        0 |        0 |               | SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST |
|  1 | TEST_TWO   |         8 | TEST_TWO   |        0 |        0 |               | SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST |
|  1 | TEST_THREE |         8 | TEST_THREE |        0 |        0 |               | SELECT * FROM DBO.SOME_NEW_TEST |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+---------------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First [`nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the `TEMPLATE_FIELD` elements a a table and then select from that table using [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the values from the attributes.

```
SELECT tf.value('@prompt', 'varchar(MAX)') prompt,
       tf.value('@data_type', 'integer') data_type,
       ...
       FROM @xml.nodes('/TEMPLATE/TEMPLATE_FIELD') tf
                                                   (tf);
```